# is this exact sequence a special case of the Snake lemma?

Tags: homological-algebra

I encountered the following exact sequence a while ago, and wondered if it was a special case of the Snake lemma. It looks like it would be, but I don't quite see how...

The context is that $A,B$ are operators on a Hilbert space $H$ (but it holds in greater generality):

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}
0 \rightarrow \ker(B) \rightarrow \ker(AB) \xrightarrow{B} \ker(A) \rightarrow H/\Im(B) \xrightarrow{A} H/\Im(AB) \rightarrow H/\Im(A) \rightarrow 0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{matrix}
0\to
&H
&\stackrel{(1,B)}{\longrightarrow}
&H\oplus H
&\stackrel{B\pi_1-\pi_2}{\longrightarrow}
&H
&\to0\\
&\downarrow\rlap{\small B}
&
&\downarrow\rlap{\small(AB,1)}
&
&\downarrow\rlap{\small A}
\\
0\to&H
&\stackrel{(A,1)}{\longrightarrow}
&H\oplus H
&\stackrel{\pi_1-A\pi_2}{\longrightarrow}
&H&\to0
\end{matrix}
This should work.

Answer (score 4):

In general, let $\alpha: L \rightarrow M$ and $\beta: M \rightarrow N$ be morphisms in an abelian category. Then

$\begin{matrix}
&L
&\stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow}
&M
&\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}
&\operatorname{coker} \alpha
&\to0\\
&\downarrow\rlap{\beta \alpha}
&
&\downarrow\rlap{\beta}
&
&\downarrow\rlap{}
\\
0\to&N
&\stackrel{\text{id}}{\longrightarrow}
&N
&\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}
&0
\end{matrix}$

yields an exact sequence
$$\ker \beta \alpha \rightarrow \ker \beta \rightarrow \operatorname{coker} \alpha \rightarrow \operatorname{coker} \beta\alpha \rightarrow \operatorname{coker} \beta \rightarrow 0$$

and

$\begin{matrix}
&0
&\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}
&L
&\stackrel{\text{id}}{\longrightarrow}
&L
&\to0\\
&\downarrow\rlap{}
&
&\downarrow\rlap{\alpha}
&
&\downarrow\rlap{\beta \alpha}
\\
0\to& \ker \beta
&\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}
&M
&\stackrel{\beta}{\longrightarrow}
&N
\end{matrix}$

yields an exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow \ker \alpha \rightarrow \ker \beta \alpha \rightarrow \ker \beta \rightarrow \operatorname{coker} \alpha \rightarrow \operatorname{coker} \beta\alpha \, .$$

It is not hard to check that the two sequences can be combined to give
$$0 \rightarrow \ker \alpha \rightarrow \ker \beta \alpha \rightarrow \ker \beta \rightarrow \operatorname{coker} \alpha \rightarrow \operatorname{coker} \beta\alpha \rightarrow \operatorname{coker} \beta \rightarrow 0 \, .$$

Comment: You don't need to apply the snake lemma twice. People rarely mention this, but it is true in general that the kernel of the first morphism in the ker-coker sequence is isomorphic to the kernel of the first morphism in the first exact sequence, so you can get the start $0 \to \ker{\alpha} \to \ker{\beta\alpha}$ from that.

Comment: @Martin: Sure, and dually, it is also true in general that $\operatorname{coker} \beta$ is a cokernel of $\operatorname{coker} \alpha \rightarrow \operatorname{coker} \beta \alpha$. I just wanted to mention that there are two diagrams for which the snake lemma gives at once almost all of the desired long exact sequence.

Comment: I see. I guess I didn't make myself very clear in my first comment. What I was trying to say is this: In the snake sequence of
$$
\begin{matrix}
&A
&\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}
&B
&\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow}
&C
&\to0\\
&\downarrow\rlap{a}
&
&\downarrow\rlap{b}
&
&\downarrow\rlap{c}
\\
0\to&A'
&\stackrel{f'}{\longrightarrow}
&B'
&\stackrel{g'}{\longrightarrow}
&C'
\end{matrix}
$$
one has that $\ker{f}$ is isomorphic to the kernel of the map $\ker{a} \to \ker{b}$ (and dually $\operatorname{coker}{g'}$ is isomorphic to the cokernel of $\operatorname{coker}b \to \operatorname{coker}c$).

Comment: Oh now I see. In fact I didn't realize this situation in the general setup of the snake lemma before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:
$$
\begin{matrix}
&H
&\stackrel{(-B,1)}{\longrightarrow}
&H\oplus H
&\stackrel{\pi_1+B\pi_2}{\longrightarrow}
&H
&\to0\\
&\downarrow\rlap{\small B}
&
&\downarrow\rlap{\small(AB,-AB)}
&
&\downarrow\rlap{\small A}
\\
0\to&H
&\stackrel{(-AB,-A)}{\longrightarrow}
&H\oplus H
&\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}
&H
\end{matrix}
$$

*Oops, after writing all down, it doesn't look that good anymore ... May have to sleep over it*

Comment: What is the map on the bottom right?

Comment: Bottom left map should be injective, but it is not in yours.

Comment: Bottom right could be $\pi_1-B\pi_2$. But then the right square is no more commutative. And indeed the bottom left is not injective without certain conditions. But there are *verisimilarly* some modifications which could solve the problem.