# Can one prove this fact about Fredholm operators like this

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

If $X,Y,Z$ are Banach spaces and $u: X \to Y. v: Y \to Z$ are Fredholm then $\mathrm{ker}(vu)$ is finite dimensional.

Can one argue as follows?:

If $x \in \mathrm{ker}(vu)$ then either $x \in \mathrm{ker}(u)$ or $u(x) \in \mathrm{ker}(v)$. Hence
$$ \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker(vu)}) \le \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker(u)}) + \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker(v)})$$

It seems to be intuitively clear but since I don't have a formal proof for the $\le$ above I am skeptical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll prove slightly more

Consider commutative diagramm
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> X @>(\begin{smallmatrix} 1_X\\ u\end{smallmatrix})>> X\oplus Y @>\begin{pmatrix} -u\; 1_Y\end{pmatrix}>> Y @>>> 0\\
@. @VVuV @VVvu\oplus 1_YV @VVvV @.\\
0 @>>> Y @>>(\begin{smallmatrix} v\\ 1_Y\end{smallmatrix})> Z\oplus Y @>>\begin{pmatrix} -1_Z\; v\end{pmatrix}> Z @>>> 0\\
\end{CD}
$$
then [by snake lemma we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436112/is-this-exact-sequence-a-special-case-of-the-snake-lemma) the following exact sequence
$$
0\to\operatorname{ker}(u)\to\operatorname{ker}(vu)\to\operatorname{ker}(v)\to\operatorname{coker}(u)\to\operatorname{coker}(vu)\to\operatorname{coker}(v)\to 0
\tag{1}
$$
Since $\operatorname{ker}(u)$, $\operatorname{coker}(u)$, $\operatorname{ker}(v)$, $\operatorname{coker}(v)$ are finite dimensional and the sequence $(1)$ is exact then $\operatorname{ker}(vu)$ and $\operatorname{coker}(vu)$ are finite dimensional too.

From rank nullity theorem it easily follows that for any exact sequence of finite dimensional vector spaces
$$
0\to V_0\to V_1\to\ldots\to V_{n-1}\to V_n\to 0
$$
holds 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \operatorname{dim}(V_i)=0
$$
Applying this theorem to $(1)$ we get
$$
\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(u)-
\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(vu)+
\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(v)-
\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{coker}(u)+
\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{coker}(vu)-
\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{coker}(v)=0
$$
Recall the definition of index
$$
\operatorname{ind}(w)=\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(w)-\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{coker}(w)
$$
to get
$$
\operatorname{ind}(v)+\operatorname{ind}(u)-\operatorname{ind}(vu)=0
$$
The last is well known index theorem for Fredholm operators.

Comment: Uhm, thank you. I understand you prove the fact but does it mean I can argue as I did or that I can't?

Answer (score 1):

While my question is still open and I'm still wondering whether I can argue as I did in my question I came up with another way of proving it:

Note that $$0 \to \mathrm{ker}(u) \xrightarrow{i} \mathrm{ker}(vu) \xrightarrow{u}\mathrm{ker}(v)  \cap u(X) \xrightarrow{v}0$$

is a short exact sequence such that $i$ has a one sided inverse. Hence by the [splitting lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) 
$$ \mathrm{ker}(vu) = \mathrm{ker}(u) \oplus \mathrm{ker}(v)  \cap u(X)$$

hence $\mathrm{ker}(vu) $ is finite dimensional.

Comment: @Norbert WOnderful! No problem at all, I'm thankful for your time!