# Any reference for induces exact sequence $0 \to Ker(f) \to Ker(gf) \to Ker(g) \xrightarrow{\delta} Coker(f) \to Coker(gf) \to Coker(g) \to 0.$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, category-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be an abelian category and $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$ morphisms in $\mathscr{C}$, then we have the following exact sequence

$$0 \to \operatorname{Ker}(f) \to \operatorname{Ker}(gf) \to \operatorname{Ker}(g) \xrightarrow{\delta} \operatorname{Coker}(f) \to \operatorname{Coker}(gf) \to \operatorname{Coker}(g) \to 0.$$

I need to use this result which I know its true since I almost got it, but instead of looking help ending the proof. I'm wondering if someone knows a book or text where I can reference this result? This one looks pretty much like the Snake Lemma but I cannot find them in Literature. Or if someone help me see this as an application of a the Snake Lemma it would also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: What's the map from $\ker(f)$ to $\ker(g)$? I don't see an obvious way to define this map—the only way you've provided to get from $A$ to $B$ is via $f$, but that sends all elements of $\ker(f)$ to zero, so how are you embedding $\ker(f)$ in $\ker(g)$?

Comment: You must be missing some hypotheses. Otherwise take $B=C=0$ and $f=g=0$. Then the sequence would have to look like $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow 0\rightarrow...$, forcing $A$ to be zero.

Comment: Sorry! It was a typos mistake, already edited my mistake. I wanted to say $0\to Ker(f) \to Ker(gf) \to Ker(f) \to....$

Comment: I guess you wanted to say $$ 0 \to \operatorname{Ker}(f)  \to \operatorname{Ker}(gf)   \to \operatorname{Ker}(g)  \to \dots $$

Comment: See also
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436112/is-this-exact-sequence-a-special-case-of-the-snake-lemma

Comment: If you just wish for a reference, this result is stated in [Milne's CFT notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf) as lemma A.2 (called there the "kernel-cokernel lemma").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a consequence of the snake lemma applied to $$\array{
  \operatorname{Ker}(f) &\to & A &\stackrel{f}{\to} & B &\to& \operatorname{Coker}(f) &\to & 0
    \\
    && \downarrow^{gf} && \downarrow^{g} && \downarrow
    \\
    0 &\to& C &\to & C &\to& 0
  }
$$
and you get
$$ 0 \to \operatorname{Ker}(f)  \to \operatorname{Ker}(gf)  \to \operatorname{Ker}(g)  \to \operatorname{Coker}(f)  \to \operatorname{Coker}(gf)  \to \operatorname{Coker}(g) \to 0$$

Comment: Thanks! But wondering how you connect $Ker(f)$ with $Ker(gf)$? Same with $Coker(f)$ with $Coker(gf)$? @Nullhomologous

Comment: They are just the natural maps (in terms of elements): an element in $Ker(f)$ is inside $Ker(gf)$, as if $f(x)=0$, then $g(f(x))=g(0)=0$. The map from $Coker(f)$ to $Coker(gf)$ are the connecting maps: take a lifting to B, apply $g$, go down to $Coker(gf)$.

Comment: Already understand the morphism $Ker(f)$ into $Ker(gf)$ but stil dont see how the conencting map from $Ker(g)$ to  $Coker (f)$? Im thinking in a diagram this way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma.  So in my head im trying to get the connecting map from $Ker(Coker(f) \to 0)$ to Coker(gf) @Nullhomologous

Comment: The map from $Ker(g) $ to $Coker(f) $ in the presentation I put is just the composition $Ker(g)\to B \to Coker(f)$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I already got your idea! Nulhomologous

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the snake lemma to the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A @>{\begin{bmatrix} id \\ f \end{bmatrix}}>> A \oplus B @>{\begin{bmatrix} -f & id \end{bmatrix}}>> B @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVfV @VV{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & id \\ gf & 0 \end{bmatrix}}V @VV{-g}V \\
0 @>>> B @>{\begin{bmatrix} id \\ g \end{bmatrix}}>> B \oplus C @>{\begin{bmatrix} -g & id \end{bmatrix}}>> C @>>> 0.
\end{CD}
$$