# Do pseudo-isomorphisms of $R$-modules satisfy the 2 of 3 property?

Tags: modules

Suppose we have $L \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} N$ where $L,M,N$ are $R$-modules and $f,g$ are homomorphisms. A pseudo-isomorphism of $R$-modules is a homomorphism with finite kernel and cokernel. Is it the case that if 2 out of the 3 maps $f,g,gf$ are pseudo-isomorphisms, then the third is as well?

Here's what I haven't been able to show:

1. If $f,gf$ are pseudo-isomorphisms, then $g$ has finite kernel.
2. If $g,gf$ are pseudo-isomorphisms, then $f$ has finite cokernel.

If those two statements can be shown, I believe the answer to my question is yes. I'd be grateful to see either a proof of the two statements above or a counter example. If the 2 of 3 property doesn't hold for $R$-modules generally, are there "nice" restrictions one can place on $L,M,N$ or $R$, so that it does hold? E.g.  $L,M,N$ are finitely generated, torsion, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give a concrete and an abstract answer.

Concretely, let's consider only case 1 you struggled with: If $f$ and $gf$ are pseudo-isomorphisms, then $g$ has finite kernel: Consider $\text{ker}(gf)\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}\text{ker}(g)$. Its domain is finite by assumption, and its cokernel $\text{ker}(g)/f(\text{ker}(fg))$ embeds into $\text{coker}(f)$, which is also finite. Hence, $\text{ker}(g)$ is finite.

Abstractly, you may want to look up the notion of a [*Serre subcategory*](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02MN): The class of finite $R$-modules is a Serre subcategory of the category of all $R$-modules, and the pseudo-isomorphisms are those morphisms mapping to isomorphisms under the corresponding quotient functor. As such, they satisfy the 2-out-of-3 property without further calculation.

Comment: This is really helpful, and it's the first I've heard of Serre subcategories. Thanks. If you have any hints for statement 2, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I'm just now rereading your answer, and I realize I misunderstood it. Your claim is that pseudo-isomorphisms of $R$-modules (not just the finite ones) do satisfy the 2-out-of-3 property. This is great news. I suppose I'd still like to see the explicit calculation of statement 2 if anyone can provide it.

Comment: I'm hoping you could clarify your answer. The corresponding quotient functor you mention is an exact functor, and so I can see that it must send pseudo-isomorphisms to isomorphisms. Certainly isomorphisms satisfy the 2-out-of-3 property, but I don't see why that implies that the pseudo-isomorphisms must also. Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

@Hanno has posted the idea of a categorical answer to my question which sounds promising, but since I can't quite follow it to the end, I wanted to post a concrete way to see why the answer to my question is *yes*.

It follows from an answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917172/any-reference-for-induces-exact-sequence-0-to-kerf-to-kergf-to-kerg-x?noredirect=1&lq=1) without much extra work. The idea is that, by applying the snake lemma to the correct diagram, we get the exact sequence $$0 \to \operatorname{ker}(f) \to \operatorname{ker}(gf) \to \operatorname{ker}(g) \to \operatorname{coker}(f) \to \operatorname{coker}(gf) \to \operatorname{coker}(g) \to 0$$

We'll also use the following easy-to-check fact:

**Lemma:** If $A \to B \to C$ is an exact sequence of $R$-modules and $A$ and $C$ are finite, then $B$ must also be finite.

The proof of the 2-out-of-3 property for pseudo-isomorphisms of $R$-modules goes as follows.

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are pseudo-isomorphisms. Then $\operatorname{ker}(f), \operatorname{ker}(g), \operatorname{coker}(f), \operatorname{coker}(g)$ are all finite. Applying our lemma to the above exact sequence immediately gives us that $\operatorname{ker}(gf)$ and $\operatorname{coker}(gf)$ must be finite, and hence $gf$ is a pseudo-isomorphism. The other two cases follow for the same reasons.